# How to re-render the react component for the async calls?

Tags: api, reactjs

I am currently using ReactJs for the project,
And I have button,when click on button, there is api call and the component should be rendered.

But as of the now, it is not happening using ComponentDidMount(),checked with ComponentWillMount() the result is same.

So can anyone let me know if i am missing anything??

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./AddCarrier.css"
import {DataTable,Alert,Loader} from 'react-pattern-library';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class AddCarrier extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={tableContent:{},tableContentAdd:{},carrier:{},responseCarrierList:{},tableContentEdit:{},carrierResponse:{},agentName:"",agentType:"",error:"",ntID:"",producerNumber:"",ux:"normal"}
        this.getList = this.getList.bind(this)
        this.addCarrier = this.addCarrier.bind(this)
        this.editCarrier = this.editCarrier.bind(this)
        this.getListCarrier = this.getListCarrier.bind(this);
    }

    getList(){
        let carrier={};
        let responseCarrierList={};
        var agentName,agentType,ntID,producerNumber;

        const url = 'http://localhost:9001/carriers';
        axios.post(url,{
            ntId:"xxxxxx"
        })
            .then(rsp => {
                if(rsp!=undefined){
                agentName = rsp.data.agentDetails[0].agentName;
                agentType = rsp.data.agentDetails[0].agentType;
                ntID=rsp.data.agentDetails[0].NTID;
                producerNumber=rsp.data.agentDetails[0].ProducerNumber;
                carrier=rsp.data.carrier;
                responseCarrierList=rsp.data.responseCarrierList;
                this.setState({carrier:carrier,responseCarrierList:responseCarrierList,agentName: agentName, agentType: agentType,ntID:ntID,producerNumber:producerNumber}); 
                this.getListCarrier();
            }
        })

    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.getList();
    }

    getListCarrier(){
        var addObj={tableBody:[]};
        var editObj={tableBody:[]};
        var addCarrierArray = []
        this.state.carrier.forEach(carrierAdd => {
        if(this.state.responseCarrierList.filter( (filterCarrier) => filterCarrier.CARRIER_NAIC_CD == carrierAdd.carrierNaicCd).length == 0){
            addCarrierArray.push(carrierAdd)} 
        })
        var carrierDetails = this.state.carrier;
        /////////////Add Carrier Component////////////
        addCarrierArray.map(carrier =>{
            var elements = {}
            elements.CarrierName = carrier.vendorNm + " - " + carrier.carrierNaicCd;
            elements.UserName = <input ref={user=> this.uname = user} type="text" id="uname" placeholder="enter username" className="c-form-field__input" data-id={carrier.carrierNaicCd}/>;
            elements.Password = <input ref={pass=> this.password = pass} type="password" id="pass" placeholder="enter password " className="c-form-field__input"/>;
            elements.Action =<button className="c-btn c-btn--secondary c-btn--sm" type="submit" onClick={this.addCarrier}>Add</button>;
            elements.SignUp = <a href={carrier.signupUrl} target="_blank">SignUp</a>;
            addObj.tableBody.push(elements)})

        /////////////Edit Carrier Component////////////
        this.state.responseCarrierList.map(carrier =>{
            var elements = {};
            elements.CarrierName = this.state.carrier.filter( (carrierFilter) => carrierFilter.carrierNaicCd == carrier.CARRIER_NAIC_CD)[0].vendorNm + " - " + carrier.CARRIER_NAIC_CD;             
            elements.UserName = <input ref={user=> this.uname = user} type="text" id="uname" defaultValue = {carrier.USERNAME} readOnly className="c-form-field__input" data-id={carrier.CARRIER_NAIC_CD}/>;
            elements.Password = <input ref={pass=> this.password = pass} type="password" id="pass" defaultValue = "******" readOnly className="c-form-field__input"/>;
            elements.Action =<button className="c-btn c-btn--secondary c-btn--sm" type="submit" onClick={this.editCarrier} id="edit">edit</button>;
            addObj.tableBody.push(elements)
            })
        this.setState({tableContentAdd: addObj,tableContentEdit:editObj});
    }

    addCarrier(event){
        const username=event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#uname").value;
        const password=event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#pass").value;
        const carrierName = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[0].innerText
        const naic = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#uname").getAttribute("data-id");
        if(username=="")
            this.setState({error:"Username is required"});
        else{
            this.setState({error:""});
            const url = 'http://localhost:9001/carriers/carrierUpdate';
            axios.post(url,{
                    producerNumber: this.state.producerNumber,
                    networkId: this.state.ntID,
                    userId:username,
                    password: password,
                    naicCode: naic
                  }).then(rsp => {
                    });
                }
        }

    editCarrier(event){
        switch(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#edit").innerText){
            case "edit":  
                event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#uname").removeAttribute("readOnly")
                event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#pass").removeAttribute("readOnly")
                event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#edit").innerText = "add"
                break;

            case "add":
                const username=event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#uname").value;
                const password=event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#pass").value;
                event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#uname").setAttribute("readOnly",true)
                event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#pass").setAttribute("readOnly",true)
                event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#edit").innerText = "edit"
                this.addCarrier(event) 
                break;             
        }        
    }
    render(){
        return (
                <div className="carrierDashboard">
                    <div className="add-carrier">
                        {(this.state.agentName!=""?<h3 className="welcome-heading">Welcome {this.state.agentName} ({this.state.agentType})</h3>:<h3/>)}
                        {(this.state.error) ? <Alert type="alert">{this.state.error}</Alert> : <span></span>}
                        {(this.state.tableContentAdd["tableBody"]!=undefined)?<DataTable data={this.state.tableContentAdd} sortable={true} className="c-table--simple"/>:<Loader />}
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem due to the state got updated after this `this.getListCarrier();`. If I'm right then it must reflect the previous changes in next call of `addCarrier()`.

The solution of this is to use a callback with `setState(newState, callback)`.

```
getList(){
    let carrier={};
    let responseCarrierList={};
    var agentName,agentType,ntID,producerNumber;
    const url = 'http://localhost:9001/carriers';
    axios.post(url,{
        ntId:"xxxxxx"
    })
        .then(rsp => {
            if(rsp!=undefined){
            agentName = rsp.data.agentDetails[0].agentName;
            agentType = rsp.data.agentDetails[0].agentType;
            ntID=rsp.data.agentDetails[0].NTID;
            producerNumber=rsp.data.agentDetails[0].ProducerNumber;
            carrier=rsp.data.carrier;
            responseCarrierList=rsp.data.responseCarrierList;   
                  this.setState({carrier:carrier,responseCarrierList:responseCarrierList,agentName: agentName, agentType: agentType,ntID:ntID,producerNumber:producerNumber}, () => this.getListCarrier() ); 
        }
    })
}
```

I hope it will help...!

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply...i tried with above code..but still the re-rendering after the button click is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

If `this.getListCarrier();` depends on the complete state being set, perhaps you can move this call to `componentDidMount()`. This way `this.getListCarrier();` will only fire when the component is fully mounted.

```
getList(){
    let carrier={};
    let responseCarrierList={};
    var agentName,agentType,ntID,producerNumber;

    const url = 'http://localhost:9001/carriers';
    axios.post(url,{
        ntId:"xxxxxx"
    })
        .then(rsp => {
            if(rsp!=undefined){
            agentName = rsp.data.agentDetails[0].agentName;
            agentType = rsp.data.agentDetails[0].agentType;
            ntID=rsp.data.agentDetails[0].NTID;
            producerNumber=rsp.data.agentDetails[0].ProducerNumber;
            carrier=rsp.data.carrier;
            responseCarrierList=rsp.data.responseCarrierList;
            this.setState({carrier:carrier,responseCarrierList:responseCarrierList,agentName: agentName, agentType: agentType,ntID:ntID,producerNumber:producerNumber}); 
        }
    })

}
componentWillMount(){
    this.getList();
}
componentDidMount(){
    this.getListCarrier();
}
```